# Can a RandomForestClassifier be used across both text labels and numeric values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I have seen examples online where a RandomForestClassifier is used for training numeric values and testing numeric values.  Likewise, I have seen RandomForestClassifier being used for training labeled data and testing labeled data.  All of that makes sense to me.  I'm diving into NLP now, and I'm looking at a dataset that has a lot of language (all customer's comments) and counts of ratings that customers posted on a website.  I'm trying to do some kind of sentiment analysis on the comments column, and see if I can predict positive, neutral, or negative sentiments.  Is this the right approach?  Is there a better way to solve a problem like this?

Here is the code that I am testing.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer (max_features=2500, min_df=7, max_df=0.8, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
processed_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(wd_list).toarray()


# split into traing set and test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(wd_list, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


# we need to train the model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
text_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0)
text_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

On the very last line of code, I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'i love smell cleanser scent wipes seems different'
```

Comment: your error is missing

Comment: Lol.  I don't know how I missed that.  Ok, I just updated my original post and I'm showing the error there.

Comment: No sklearn classifier works on columns of anything other than numeric data. In the code you posted, you used a tfidfvectorizer to transform you text data to numeric correctly, but then you tried to fit your classifier to the _untransformed_ data. You should be passing in `processed_features ` not `wd_list`